# Compare Assertion in Jmeter

Tags: validation, compare, jmeter, response, assertion

I am new to J meter. Please look into the following body data in Http request

{
    "groupBy":"${groupBy}",
    "offset":0,
    "limit":10
}

I need to check whether limit value is above 10 in the above content. Is it can be done by using Compare Assertion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special Test Element - [JSON Path Assertion](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) which is designed for working with JSON data.

The relevant JSON Path expression to match your "limit" will be as simple as:

```
$.limit
```

[image: JSON Path Assertion Demo]

Try to avoid Compare Assertion where possible as it consumes **very** much resources.

References:

- [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract the value "10" in to variable using "Regular Expression Extractor" after that use "Response Assertion" by choosing "Jmeter Variable" option under "Apply to" choosing "Equals" option under "Pattern Matching Rules"
and add 10 under "Pattern to test"